# Ordering of virtual resources

Tags: puppet

I've looked for examples of ordering with virtual resources, but I can't find any. How can I set dependencies/ordering with them? This fails the syntax check:

#### test.pp

```
@file { "/usr/local/new-dir":
  ensure => directory,
}

realize( File["/usr/local/new-dir"] )
->
exec { "copy old stuff to new":
  command => "cp -R /usr/local/old-dir /usr/local/new-dir",
}
```

and testing the syntax:

```
$ puppet parser validate test.pp
err: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '->' at /home/vagrant/test.pp:6
err: Try 'puppet help parser validate' for usage
```

I can think of lots of times I would want to order virtual resources, so how is it done?

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a collector instead of realize, and then, apply ordering:

```
@file { "/usr/local/new-dir":
  ensure => directory,
}

exec { "copy old stuff to new":
  command => "cp -R /usr/local/old-dir /usr/local/new-dir",
}

File <| title == "/usr/local/new-dir" |> -> Exec["copy old stuff to new"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
@file { "/usr/local/new-dir":
    ensure => directory,
}

realize( File["/usr/local/new-dir"] )

exec { "copy old stuff to new":
    command => "cp -R /usr/local/old-dir /usr/local/new-dir",
    require => File["/usr/local/new-dir"],
}
```

I generally consider preferring the `require/before` metaparameters over the `->` chaining operators to be a good practice. But that's just me.

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated. I can't mark both answers correct, which they both are, but Raul was in first so he gets the tick, sorry about that! I wish there were more options… :/ I was wondering why you consider `require/before` better than the chaining operators?

Comment: They are more flexible and powerful - they will work in any manifest layout. They are also more explicit, especially to the untrained eye. - Again, this is quite subjective. - And yes, Raul's way is perfectly valid, just wanted to add my 2c :-)

Comment: Thanks. As I'm still getting used to Puppet it's good to get the subjective opinions too :)